# MS Edge api error "browser is not defined"

Tags: javascript, browser, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

I am trying to build an extension for new Microsoft Edge browser. After loading the unpacked extension I am getting this error,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: browser is not defined

I have read the microsoft edge docs that all extension APIs are under the `browser` namespace.

I have included storage permission in my `manifest.json` file. This my code from `manifest.json` file,

```json
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Demo",
  "author": "Plaban Kumar Mondal",
  "description": "Demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon128.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "16": "icon16.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "48": "icon48.png",
      "16": "icon16.png"
    },
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "options_page": "options/options.html",
  "permissions": ["activeTab", "storage"]
}
```

this is my javascript file where I am using the `browser` namespace,

```js
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");

checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
  return checkbox.addEventListener("change", () => {
    if (checkbox.changed) {
      browser.storage.local.set({ [checkbox.name]: true }, () => {
        browser.storage.onChanged.addListener(() => console.log("true"));
      });
    } else {
      browser.storage.local.set({ [checkbox.name]: false }, () => {
        browser.storage.onChanged.addListener(() => console.log("changed to false"));
      });
    }
  });
});
```

what is the problem with my code?

Comment: Are you testing on Edge v44 and earlier, or Edge v79 and later? They're very different browsers. (There were no v45-v78.)

Comment: I am testing on Edge v85.

Comment: @Plaban, I agree with the suggestion given by the Abhinav for replacing the `browser` with `chrome` may help you to fix the issue. Let us know, whether it works for you or not.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT I tried `chrome` and it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with `chrome` - for chromium-based edge, the browser will support the code below - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium

```
const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll("input[type='checkbox']");

checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
  return checkbox.addEventListener("change", () => {
    if (checkbox.changed) {
      chrome.storage.local.set({ [checkbox.name]: true }, () => {
        chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(() => console.log("true"));
      });
    } else {
      chrome.storage.local.set({ [checkbox.name]: false }, () => {
        chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener(() => console.log("changed to false"));
      });
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: why using `chrome` namespace?

Comment: The latest version of Edge will support chromium.  Now you can install chrome extension in ms edge browser.  I am using Version 85.0.564.44 (Official build) (64-bit). Final recommendation, Please try with "chrome". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/extensions-chromium/

Comment: @Abhinav - That information belonged in the answer, not just as a comment on it.

Comment: Understood. Thanks for your information. I am new for this stock over flow.